# Track changes missed by not using "check out and open" a file in perforce

Tags: perforce, aem, p4v

I have a few files that have been edited by an external IDE, I forgot to Check Out the files before making the changes however when I look at the files through P4V the files have changed but the indicator for the file itself shows as nothing has changed. How can I ensure my changes are committed without loosing what I have done?

One way I was thinking was to making a copy of the file, revert, check out, copy content or replace file.

That is OK with a few files but what happens when you have done so with hundreds of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "check out" command doesn't modify the local file, so you can just do that on its own without having to make a backup copy of the file first.  (What you want to avoid doing is "get latest", although if the local files are writable, Perforce will automatically balk at updating them by default because of this exact situation.)

If you have lots of files that might or might not have been modified in different ways, use Actions > Reconcile Offline Work, or "p4 reconcile" from the command line.  This will find the locally modified files and open them for the appropriate action.

Answer (score 1):

The P4V way to do this is called "Reconcile Offline Work": http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Offline.html

Or, at the command line, you can use 'p4 reconcile': http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_reconcile.html